# Save all temporary and permanent files in just one folder while running a model using ModelBuilder in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

Is it possible to save all temporary and permanent files thats derived from a model created in ModelBuilder using ArcMap in just one folder thats predefined but with relative path. I am asking this question as I wish to run my model on different laptops.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @Hornbydd](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330338/save-all-temporary-and-permanent-files-in-just-one-folder-while-running-a-model#comment538838_330338):

> You can set the environment setting output workspace at the model
>   level and any tools that honour that setting will pick it up unless
>   you have overridden it at the tool level.